# Using NTILE with less than 100 records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics

I am using `NTILE(100)` to calculate the 95th percentile value in my column. In some cases where the number of records is less than 100, `NTILE(100)` returns a NULL when queried for the values in the 95th quartile because there are not enough values. I am doing this currently in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(val int)
GO

INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(6);

SELECT val, Quantile
FROM
(
    SELECT val, NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY val) AS Quantile
    FROM
    #Temp
) A
WHERE Quantile=95

GO

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

I was wondering what is the accepted standard for handling a case with less than 100 values in the column. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why was this voted to be migrated to Superuser?

Comment: Can you show some code how you use `NTILE`. I really do not understand how `NTILE` can return null.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Sorry about being so vague. I clarified and added extra details to my question as to when I am getting a `NULL`. It was not so much about `NTILE` returning me a `NULL` but rather it was the way I was querying it.

Comment: You have your terminology a bit mixed up. By definition, quartiles divide a recordset into 4 - you are looking for the 95th percentile.

Comment: What result would you expect in the example you have provided?

Comment: @Ed Harper: Sorry! That was a typo. I meant a quantile. About the result, well, `R` gives me a value of 5.75.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to this for a client project that was still on SQL Server 2005. Since NTILE just divides the available rows into groups, you'll never get higher than 6 with 6 rows. If you want to spread them out to look like percentiles (ex: 16, 33, 50, 66, 83, 100)
you can do the following. Note that you won't necessarily hit 95 exactly so you need to query for the closest value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 val, Quantile
FROM
(
    SELECT val, CAST (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) OVER() AS INT) AS Quantile
    FROM #Temp
) A
WHERE Quantile >= 95 
ORDER BY Quantile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that when you say "`NTILE(100)` returns a NULL when queried for the values in the 95th quartile because there are not enough values", you mean that when there are less than 100 values, you get a null, rather than because `NITLE(100)` itself.

When you have a small set of data, NTILE() is not a good option. `NTILE(100)` divides the data into 100 subdivisions, but in your case, there're only 6 values. So the greatest value 6 has a corresponding output of 6.

As for your question, I'd suggest going with `PERCENT_RANK()`, which returns the relative percentile of each row.

In the 6 values case, no value is gonna be the exact 95th percentile. So I'll output the value closest to 95th.

```
   WITH sub AS(SELECT 
       val,
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY val) AS percentile
   FROM temp)

    SELECT  *
   FROM sub
   ORDER BY ABS(percentile - 0.95)  
   LIMIT 1
```